# .End(xlToRight) within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I've just got a quick one wondering if I can somehow alter the following snippet to include `.End(xlToRight)` instead of defining `L6` (the result is the same).

```
Sub Test()
Dim LastCol As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
    .Range(Range("A5"), LastCol).Copy    

    .Range("B5:L5", Range("B5:L5").Offset(LastRow - FirstRow, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

    .Range("B6", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    .Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks for any help :)

**EDIT: updated pdw TonyDallimore *(see response below)***

*Tony, the above code is the sum of what I've been trying to get working. Within the `with` statement, I'm looking to copy the contents of row 5, and paste them down to the nth row - which is defined by a list already present in columnA. The last line per your advice will then paste the values of all but the top row (r5) to preserve transparency for the user, while minimising file size.
The middle bit is the remaining 'work in progress', as L5 is not certain to be the farmost column.*

Answer (score 5):

**Both questions**

`.End(xxx)` is the same as `Ctrl+Arrow` from the keyboard and stops at the first cell that is different from the current cell.  So if you start at a cell with a value it stops at a cell without a value or vice versa.

The trouble with starting top left and using `xlDown` and `xlToRight` is that it will stop at a blank cell in the middle of your table.  Fine if you absolutely cannot have a blank cell in the middle, but `XlUp` or `xlToLeft` from bottom right are safer.

**Question 1**

Is your problem that `.End(xxx).Column` will return 12 and you do not know how to turn it into the letter "L"?

Is so, there are lots of choices.  I think the easiest is to remember that

`.Cells(6,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address`

would return "$L$6".

**Question 2**

Does `.Cells(1000, ColRange)` represent the bottom right cell?

`.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` might be an easier option.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Question(1) relates to me simply not knowing how to include xlToRight in the code snippet (very basic I know, but I just cant figure it out and wasting too much time trying!). Your suggestion to the second question is spot on as always :)

Comment: To give you an example, here was my first attempt: Range("B6", Range("B6").End(xlToRight), Range("B6", Range("B6").End(xlToRight)).Offset(LastRow - FirstRow, 0)).Copy

Comment: Excel offers half-a-dozen different ways of achieving the same task. We all use the ways that seem easiest to us and you are using syntax I almost never use. It looks to me as though you are trying to paste the range B6 to bottom right over itself so as to replace formulae with values. If you are, I would go for something like: `With Sheets("xxx")` `.Range("B6", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy` `.Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` `End With`

Comment: Yes that's what this snippet is try to do - I've updated the question above to be more accurate and expand what I'm looking to do. Nearly there, thanks so much for your help again.

Comment: Having said I would do something like xxxx, I should admit that I wouldn't.  I would use `.Range(.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft), .Cells(RowBot, ColRight)` and would set RowTop, ColLeft, RowBot and ColRight individually.  I am not concerned with how much I can cram into a single statement; I am concerned about the time it takes me to get it right and that I will not understand the statement in six months when I have to update it.  How much time did that missing dot in the middle of a Union statement cost you?

Comment: In `.Range(Range("A5"), LastCol).Copy` LastCol is a string so you need Range(LastCol). I have not tested this code so I do not guarantee this is the only error. As per my previous comment, I would make LastCol an integer and set it to `.Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` I would then use `.Range(.Cells(5,"A"), .Cells(5,LastCol)).Copy`. Because I always use this syntax, I always understand it.  I want my code to work as quickly as possible; I do not care whether it makes me look clever or not.